# How to create an Account in Salesforce via Soap Enterprise API in PHP?

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce

got a problem with the creation of Account in Salesfoce with the SOAP API using enterprise.wsdl

Using this code

```
$mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$mySforceConnection -> createConnection("soapclient/enterprise.wsdl.xml");
try {$mySforceConnection -> login(USERNAME, PASSWORD, SECURITY_TOKEN);}
  catch (Exception $e) {echo "Connection not possible<br>";}

  $record = new stdClass();
  $record-> Name = 'test der API';
  $record-> Website = 'www.test.de';
  $response = $mySforceConnection -> create($record,'Account');
```

Got the error message:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$result in xyz on line 499
```

Can someone help on this? Thanks

Best
Thomas

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? It seems incompatible with PHP 7 at this point.

Answer (score 0):

mySforceConnection->create() expects first argument to be array of records.
Change the line to the following fixes the issue for me and creates the record successfully:

```
$response = $mySforceConnection->create(array($record),'Account');
```

You might still get Notices but the functionality seems to work.

Comment: Thank you. I found the error I made. Your hint was very good. I mixedupEnterprise.wsdl with the partners.wsdl . Secondly I used PHP 7 instead of PHP 5.6 . Therefore this error message appears. 

Now it is working